# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type babel and webpack

Tags: webpack, babeljs

So my file structure is pretty straight forward.

~

```
/dist
/node_modules
/src
.babelrc
index.js
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

What I am trying to accomplish is I am trying to run this command "webpack" then have it build into my dist folder my compiled code. I am then module.exporting it out to use it.

However, I keep running into this error that says that I may need an appropriate loader for this file type. I feel as if I have all of my dev devependies that I need for it to compile.

Here are my following webpack.config.js as well as my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.8.1"
  }
}


 module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/components/select.jsx'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + /dist/,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'form-field.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't allow any file types in your loader. Add a `test` key.

```
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
      presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
    }
  }]
```

Comment: Ahh, I just realized that. Even with adding the test I am still getting this error. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: Please include the require call that's failing and the full error.

Comment: ERROR in ./src/components/select.jsx
Module parse failed: /src/components/select.jsx Unexpected token (6:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     render() {
|         return (
|             <div>
|                 <select>
|                     <option> One </option>
 @ multi ./src/components/select.jsx , edited webpack.config for reference also